# How do we get back a specific session using sessionId?

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, websphere

I work on a task that involves moving/traversing from one application to another. The applications are in separate JVMs.

While traversing to the other application, I keep track of the session ID. However, as I traverse back and forth, a new session gets created.  Is there any way for me to get back the same session, using the sessionId that I retain, when I navigate back into my parent application from a child application?

Environment: J2EE with WebSphere.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mork0075, the sessionID is tied to the cookie name and the server domain. If you're using the same server domain for two apps on separate JVMs, I see two options to maintain the session when switching between applications:

The long shot:
1) If you're using a database for session replication purposes, you can use the same database for both applications, and the sessionID will be available for both apps. The one problem I see here is that the objects in the session may not be available on both sides, since the code would be different etc. They'd probably clobber the other side's session objects unless you maintained the code and such on both sides so the objects were available.

The likely possibility:
2) Use different cookie names for the session on one of the two apps. By default, sessions use JSESSIONID as the cookie, and when you switch to the second app, it tries to look up a session based on that cookiename and can't find it. So, it creates a new sessionID and sends it back to the browser, thus causing your sessionID to change and not be available when you switch back to the original app. However, if you change the second app's sessionID to something else (say, JSESSIONID2) your browser would end up with two valid sessionIDs that would each be valid on their correct application. You can change the name via the administration console under the application server's Session Management->Enable cookies page.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if this helps, but in a ONE application scenario, you would submit a sessionID with every reponse, save it in the URL, a cookie or as a hidden field. By submitting a new request to the server, the sessionID is also submitted, to resolve it at server side. In my understand switching from one application to another means, that you have to give the sessionID with the user, across the applications. If you save the sessionID in a cookie, this perhaps is not possible, because the cookie is restricted to a certain server domain. So ensure that the session is still valid and the sessionID is present after returning to the application started.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to do this manually. Most app servers support Single Sign On (SSO) so that you can log in to one application and have access to all the applications in the same SSO domain. The app server will keep track of session ids and link them to an HTTPSession object specific to the web app.

See http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/csec_sso.html